# How to Make a Simple Send a Message HTML with Running Validations

Tags: javascript, html

I think I got the logic pretty much done with my webpage, the only problem I have now is that the "Send" button won't execute the javascript "alert()" function.

Here's my HTML codes :

```
<body>
<h1>Send us a message</h1>
<form name = "info">
Name: <input type = "text" id = "inf" name = "name" placeholder="Enter a valid name" >*</br></br>
Email Address: <input type="email" id = "inf" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" >*</br></br>
Phone Number: <input type = "tel" id = "inf" name ="PN"  placeholder="Enter a valid phone number" >*</br></br>
<textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Write Your Message Here..."></textarea><br><br>
<input type ="button" value = "Send" onclick="alert()">
</form>
</body>
```

Here's My Javascript codes :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ValEntry(){
    var valid = true;

    if ( document.info.name.value== ""||document.info.email.value== ""||document.info.PN.value == "" )
    {
        alert ( "Please fill up the remaining text boxes" );
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}

function checkemail(){
    var testresults1
    var str=document.info.email.value
    var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i

    if (filter.test(str))
    testresults1=true
    else{
    alert("Please input a valid email address!")
    testresults1=false
    }
return (testresults1)
}

function checkphone(){
    var testresults2
    var int = document.info.PN.value
    var filter2= /[1-9]/g;

    if (filter2.test(int))
    testresults2=true
    else{
    alert("Please input a valid phone number!")
    testresults2=false
}
return (testresults2)
}

function validate(){
    if (document.info.email.value)
    return checkemail()
    else{
    return true
    }       
}

function validate2(){
    if (document.info.PN.value)
    return checkphone()
    else{
    return true
    }       
}

function FinalVal(){
    return ValEntry() && validate() && validate2();

}

function alert(){
    FinalVal();
    {
       var fields=["name"];
       var msg = "";
       msg += "The message has been sent " + document.info[ fields ].value + "!";
       alert("msg");
    }
    return true;
}


</script>
```

Comment: why re-designing the wheel when all that is already available with [jQueryValidation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) ... or is something to learn/test/play?

Comment: Testing it so I can learn it for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your call to alert(). I will bet that you are just getting an empty alert box when you click the button...

```
<input type ="button" value = "Send" onclick="alert()">
```

This is a built in javascript function and you are trying to define your own with the same name. Rename that function to almost anything else and it will work for you.

```
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="testSubmit()">

function testSubmit(){
    FinalVal();

    var fields=["name"];
    var msg = "";
    msg += "The message has been sent " + document.info[ fields ].value + "!";
    alert("msg");

    return true;
}
```